# How can I cast and check for NULL all at the same time in F#?

Tags: f#

In C# one can use [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for casting reference type values to either a requested type or null, so that it's only needed for the cast value to be checked for being null before being used. How do I do it in F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pattern matching  and the `:? <type> as <value>` pattern. F# does not like `null` values so it does not automatically give you `null` if the value is not of the right type (or if it was null previously). You can handle `null` and values of other types in a second branch:

```
let o = box (System.Random())
match o with
| :? System.Random as rnd -> rnd.Next()
| _ -> -1
```

If you really wanted to get `null` value, you could use `Unchecked.defaultof`, but that is probably not a good idea and it could lead to errors:

```
let castAs<'T> (o:obj) = 
  match o with :? 'T as t -> t | _ -> Unchecked.defaultof<'T>

castAs<System.Random> null                     // = null
castAs<System.Random> "hi"                     // = null
castAs<System.Random> (box (System.Random()))  // = random
```

Comment: is boxing necessary if I know for sure that I am dealing with a reference type?

Comment: No, the boxing is not necessary. I included it simply to make the example interesting (casting from `System.Random` to `System.Random` would always work and the compiler would tell you :-))